# How to set Docusign "signInEachLocation" in Node.js using docusign-esign npm package

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I was trying to create a **Docusign** envelope using [**docusign-esign**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docusign-esign) package.

What I need is to **force the signer to draw his/her signature** and I found out that setting the property "**signInEachLocation**" to **true** will do the trick.

Now my question is **how or where** should I set the property?

Is it here? Because when I try to execute the code, **no error** returned but it is **not working**.

```
let signer = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
   email: 'test@email.com',
   name: 'Signer Name',
   roleName: 'signer',
   signInEachLocation: true, //this property
   tabs: tabs
});
```

Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signInEachLocation property is part of the Signer object, not the TemplateRole. When you add the parameter to TemplateRole, the API is just ignoring the extra parameter instead of flagging it with an error.

[This code example](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/lib/eSignature/eg008CreateTemplate.js#L169) shows how you can add a Signer to a Template and you can add the signInEachLocation property there. See the [API reference](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/enveloperecipients/#signer-recipient) for more info.

Comment: Paige's answer is correct, but you should also know that this feature has not yet been activated for all developer accounts. Until we do that - you may need to reach out to DocuSign support to enable this feature in your account.

Comment: Paige and @Inbar, Sorry I am very new to Docusign. Can you please provide a code sample? my scenario is that I already have a template created in Web UI but I need to add a signer dynamically using nodejs and that signer should draw each signature (3 signature fields) instead of dragging and drop.

Comment: 1. Create a new developer account here - https://go.docusign.com/o/sandbox/?ga=2.70927056.1363819232.1590515244-192278368.1546193875&ECID=20890&elqCampaignId=20890&LS=NA_DEV_BOTH_BetaSite_2020-05&utm_campaign=NA_DEV_BOTH_BetaSite_2020-05&Channel=DDCUS000016968056&cName=DocuSign.com
2. change true to 'true' as a string

Answer (score 1):

This feature was added to all new developer accounts created in 2021.

If your account was created prior to 2021, [create a new](https://go.docusign.com/o/sandbox/?ga=2.70927056.1363819232.1590515244-192278368.1546193875&ECID=20890&elqCampaignId=20890&LS=NA_DEV_BOTH_BetaSite_2020-05&utm_campaign=NA_DEV_BOTH_BetaSite_2020-05&Channel=DDCUS000016968056&cName=DocuSign.com) one and you'll have this feature.

Sample Node code:

```
        let signer1 = docusign.Signer.constructFromObject({
           email: 'test@sample.com',
           name: 'some name',
           clientUserId: '1',
           recipientId: 1,
           signInEachLocation: 'true' // signer must draw their signature in each tab
        });
       let signHere1 = docusign.SignHere.constructFromObject({
          YPosition: '200',
          XPosition: '200',
          documentId: '1',
          pageNumber: '1'
     });
      let signHere2 = docusign.SignHere.constructFromObject({
         YPosition: '100',
         XPosition: '100',
         documentId: '1',
         pageNumber: '1'
     });
     let signer1Tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
        signHereTabs: [signHere1, signHere2]});
     signer1.tabs = signer1Tabs;
     let recipients = docusign.Recipients.constructFromObject({
     signers: [signer1]});
```

Comment: Do you mean if I create a new account, the only thing I need to change in my code is to set true to 'true'? Or I still need to create singer from the Singer Object and set it from there.

Comment: are you using a template?

Comment: Yes I already have a template created in Docusign website.

Comment: So, the template's recipient is not set to "sign in each location" but you want to do that from code? if you can't do that from the web app UI - you won't be able to do that from code.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I was thinking about my old account. I missed the point that if I create new account, then I can set it from API since it will be available already. That means I can also set it from web app UI. Thank you very much.

Comment: Setting it in web still doesn't solve my problem. I still need to set the "sign in each location" in Singer Object since I am adding signer dynamically to that template using API. Can you please give me a sample code?

Comment: see my answer, added some node code to show

Comment: Thank You very much. Now made it working.